# Running batch queries using the bq command line tool

Tags: google-bigquery

Seems like the flag `--batch` has no use when set within the `bq query` command:

```
bq query "SELECT name,count FROM mydataset.mytable WHERE myfield = 'condition' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 6" --batch
```

The command above runs the query straight away.

I'm running version 2.0.7 of BigQuery CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parser for command flags works like this:

`bq [global flags] <command> [command flags] [command parameters]`

Unfortunately the parser silently drops flags specified after the arguments, so it's not clear this is what happened to your command line.

To specify `--batch`, you would have to put it immediately after "query" like so:

`bq query --batch "SELECT name,count FROM mydataset.mytable WHERE ..."`

Since batch mode queries can take a long time, I suggest you run the query async like so:

`bq --nosync query --batch "SELECT name,count FROM mydataset.mytable WHERE ..."`

Comment: Thanks Michael. The Google guys should amend [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/cli_tool#runningquery) accordingly then.